# ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

There were before `aspdotnet1.0` include/exclude sections on `project.json` file

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Where is this section in ASP.NET Core 1.1 (there is no `project.json`)? 
Are there similar sections on `.csproj` file or `.pubxml`?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

> From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/csproj): if you wish to specify, for example, some files to get published with your app, you can still use the known mechanisms in `csproj` for that (for example, the `<Content>` element).

There is a `CopyToPublishDirectory` attribute for `ItemGroup` [elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) that determines whether to copy the file to the publish directory and can have one of the following value:

- Always,
- PreserveNewest
- Never

Note, that there is also similar `CopyToOutputDirectory` attribute for output folder.

Example (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj)):

```
<ItemGroup>

  <None Include="notes.txt" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToOutputDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->

  <Content Include="files\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  <None Include="publishnotes.txt" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToPublishDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->
</ItemGroup>
```

---

If you are interesting how `project.json -.csproj` migration use `CopyToPublishDirectory` attribute to migrate publish options, you may look into [MigratePublishOptionsRule](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-migrate/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectJsonMigration/Rules/MigratePublishOptionsRule.cs) class in dotnet cli repo.

Comment: MigratePublishOptionsRule link is dead.

Comment: This answer is for project before Visual Studio 2017 15.3. Please refer to @Wagner-Pereira for the latest projects

Comment: I have 
 <ItemGroup>
  <None Update="readme.html">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="readme.md">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
 </ItemGroup>

I want the readme.html to be copied during publish but it's not doing it.

Comment: This work using .Net 6 CLI

Answer (score 85):

In `.csproj` for Visual Studio versions 15.3 and higher, this keeps the files visible in Visual Studio (whereas "Content Remove" does not), and prevents the files from being published.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For excluding the content of a folder you need to write:

```
<!-- Excluding the ClientApp folder. -->
<Content Update="ClientApp\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than accepted answer! Note the Update attribute so that you can apply it to files which have been already included in project by default because they are under the root folder

Comment: I also agree. This also works in VS 2019, version 16.0.0 (just tested)

Comment: Works for me. Reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exclude-files

Comment: Confirmed that this still works. Tried everything above and nothing worked, but this one did.

Comment: I can comfirm this solution has worked for me on Visual Studio 2022 / .Net Core 6

Comment: Can I specify here that only appsettings file from current project must be published? I need to exclude appsettings files from dependence projects.

Comment: It is worth it to mention that for excluding the content of a folder you need to write `<!-- Excluding the ClientApp folder. -->
    <Content Update="ClientApp\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />`

Answer (score 41):

**After Visual Studio 2017 15.3**

Edit the .csproj file to manually exclude files/folder from being published

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="src\**" />
  <Content Remove="node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

ref: https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/273/fixing-the-duplicate-content-error-after-upgrading-visual-studio-2017

Comment: This is the solution that works now. CopyToPublishDirectory or CopyToOutputDirectory haven't worked at all after 15.3

Comment: Unfortunately this removes your modules also from the VS solution explorer and you'll lose tooling support. `CopyToPublishDirectory` works fine for me with 17.5.

Comment: This is the only way we could get this to work also in VS 2022. Not sure if there are other publish settings that make the old way work.

We ended up updating all the files using the properties panel to **None->DoNotCopy** and the find-replace the csproj file with from **<None Remove** to **<Content Remove**

Comment: This is the only solution working for Rider.

Comment: On Rider, using `Remove` attribute also hides the file(s) in the solution explorer. Using `Update` in place of `Remove` with `CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"` fixed the issue while preserving the file's visibility in the solution explorer.

Comment: This method doesn't exclude files included by referencing a NuGet package, which contains the unwanted file.

Answer (score 23):

With **Visual Studio 2017** (tested in 15.6.5), you can right-click on the file in the **Solution Explorer** and set the **Build Action** to **None**.

It will update your `.csproj` file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
  <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
  <Content Remove="npm-shrinkwrap.json" />
  <Content Remove="package.json" />
  <Content Remove="tsconfig.json" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="appsettings.Development.json" />
  <None Include="appsettings.json" />
  <None Include="npm-shrinkwrap.json" />
  <None Include="package.json" />
  <None Include="tsconfig.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just seen your answer after finding the same solution for vs2019^^. So I'm only adding this information: this solution also works for vs2019 (and is the best and easiest way to prevent a file from being published IMHO).

Answer (score 18):

For Visual Studio 2019, I managed to exclued a wwwroot subfolder named "dummy" (including all subfolders of "dummy") from publish output using the following code:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\dummy\**\*">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Note: The requirement was to keep the wwwroot and its subfolder(s) included in project but just exclude while publishing.

Answer (score 12):

To exclude files on publish, edit your publish file, e.g. `FolderProfile.pubxml`, and add the appropriate XML elements shown below to include/exclude files and folders.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <PublishFramework />
    <ProjectGuid>afa9f185-7ce0-4935-9da1-ab676229d68a</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\PublishOutput</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>

    <!-- CopyToPublishDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->

    <!-- Copying a file located outside of the project into the published site's wwwroot folder. -->
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="..\ReadMe2.md">
      <RelativePath>wwwroot\ReadMe2.md</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>

    <!-- Excluding the wwwroot\Content folder. -->
    <Content Update="wwwroot\Content\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />

    <!-- Excluding the Views\Home\About2.cshtml file. -->
    <Content Update="Views\Home\About2.cshtml" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

See also: [Visual Studio publish profiles - Selective file inclusion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#selective-file-inclusion)

Comment: This method doesn't exclude files included by referencing a NuGet package, which contains the unwanted file.

Answer (score 8):

The Solution from @Craig Wilson worked great to pubish with Visual Studio 2022 and Core 6

The following is a sample to exclude all appsettings except for appsettings.json and also the appsetting.QA.json  when you setup an Environment Variable at a system level like  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=QA

In windows, you can also setup the environment variable on the fly in the same powershell you use to run the dotnet pubish command.

$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = 'QA'

That variable will be drop when you close that powershell

```
    <!-- Publish Settings -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="appsettings.*.json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>  
        <Content Update="appsettings.$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT).json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>  
        <Content Update="appsettings.$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT).json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>      
    </ItemGroup>
```

Please note, in Visual studio 2022 all files are included by default and you just need to use Update

Comment: This method doesn't exclude files included by referencing a NuGet package, which contains the unwanted file.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I need **local.settings.json** locally during debug, but I do not want it included in my WebDeploy zip file during Release builds or  Publish:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\local.settings.json" Link="local.settings.json" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\local.settings.json" Link="local.settings.json" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**

Comment: Why add that second condition for release? Isn't `Never` the default behaviour anyway?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that my folders with a few files in them were not being published- I tried right clicking the folders in the project to see if I could select an option to include the folder with the deployment- it's not there, but I did find if I select the files inside the folder and mark them to copy on deployment, it will copy the files *and* create their folder in the process.

This helps if your folder has files, but doesn't help if your folders are empty.

Comment: This really helps me.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit the .csproj file to manually exclude files/folder from being published.**

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104818/ms-visual-studio-how-to-exclude-certain-project-folders-from-publishing)

For web deployment see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-applications-project-file/.

`project.json` has been now replaced by `csproj`. You can read about it more on https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj.

For Upgrading Existing .NET Core 1.0 Projects or for using Using .NET Core 1.1 you can read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/.

Comment: Yes, I know about csproj instead of project.json, but where is include/exclude secion?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**In Visual Studio 2019**,

1. Right-click the file -> Properties
2. Copy To Output Directory-> Copy always

[image]

3. Save the solution and try publish

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2022:
Unload csproj, open the file
To add content and the subfolders, insert:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Update="StaticContent\**">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio 2019:

1. Go to the "Properties" for the file in the "Solution Explorer"
2. Change the "Copy to Output Directory" property to the desired value ("Copy always", "Do not copy", "Copy if newer").