# .Net Core - Referenced file is not found when publish

Tags: file, asp.net-core, imagesharp

Im using ImageSharp with .Net Core to process some images. To load the images and fonts I do as follows:

```
_image = Image.Load(@"Resources/imgs/quote_background.png");

_fonts = new FontCollection();
_font = _fonts.Install(@"Resources/fonts/Cousine-Italic.ttf");

// Image processing...
```

My files tree looks like:

```
    - Solution
    - - MyApp
    - - - Controllers
    - - - Models
    - - - - Code.cs // This is where the above code is
    - - - wwwroot
    - - - Resources
    - - - - imgs
    - - - - fonts
```

When I am launching the application through visual studio it works fine, it finds the image. But when I deploy to AWS or to my local IIS I get the following error:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Resources\imgs\quote_background.png'.
```

What is the right way to reference this image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ContentRootPath from the IHostingEnvironment, which requires you to inject an IHostingEnvironment into your controller, e.g.:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ImageController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var image = Image.Load(String.Format(@"{0}/Resources/imgs/quote_background.png", 
            _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
        //etc...
    }
}
```

There is also WebRootPath which gets you to the wwwroot.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the answer. I did as you said and still got the same error. It seems it is mapping to the same directory as before... When I publish the project the Resource folder indeed is not generated... Do you think I have to configure something...?

Comment: OK, see the other answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713770/934407), are your images actually being published?

Comment: Thanks Matt... It did solve although I had to manually edit my .csproj because visual studio was prompting an error when I tried to set the properties...

Answer (score 2):

You want to make sure you mark the files in your `Resources` folder as 'Copy to Output Directory' = 'Copy if newer'

[image: Property screen shot showing copy to output directy set to copy if newer]

that will make sure the files end up in your output when you publish the site.