# ASP.NET core include files on publishing

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to include some files on publishing and put them in specific folder.

I would like to put all report files (*.rdlc) in folder *Reports* in the publish location.

I tried with:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Reports\**\*.rdlc"
             PackagePath="\Reports"
             CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But it always puts files in to the root of the published destination.

Comment: Try `<Content Include="../Reports/**/*.rdlc" PackagePath="Reports/"  CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish)

Comment: I saw that post, but it does not work for me. It seems that Content does not recognize PackagePath attribute. It put files into root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find solution:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <ReportFiles Include="..\Reports\**\*.rdlc">
        <Path>\Reports</Path>
    </ReportFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PrepublishScript"
        BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReportFiles)"
          DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\%(Path)"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks. For other people, just be careful with the double dots of the include. If your folder is at the project level, you need to use only one.