# How to exclude all folders containing Csla.Resources.dll from publish in dot net core?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csla

I'm using CSLA framework with dot net core 2.0.

When I do publish (`dotnet publish -c Release -r ...`) using Release configuration additional folders (tr, sv, sr) to name few of them, contains Csla.Resources.dll and they are copied in output publish folder ( ~/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/centos.7-x64/publish).

How to **exclude** these folders (with the file) or delete them from publish folder, once when `dotnet publish` finish executing?

**Note**
File "Csla.resources.dll" doesn't exist before deploy process start. 
It will be generated when `dotnet publish` started.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish)

Comment: @ITGoran, How about this issue? Have you resolve this issue? If not, could you please let me know the latest status for this issue?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I've now tried answer provided by Martin Ullrich but it doesn't work because files "Csla.resources.dll" are generated during 'dotnet publish' process and doesn't exist before.

Comment: I don't think this is actually related to Csla; I'd guess this would happen with any assembly which provides localized resource assemblies.

Comment: @Andy I think you right,  I use Cake script to remove not needed assets.

Answer (score 1):

> How to exclude these folders (with the file) or delete them from publish folder, once when dotnet publish finish executing?

According to the below document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/web-publishing-vs?tabs=aspnetcore2x

You can use `CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"` to excluding files and folders:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot/content/**/*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where exactly those files are, you can use msbuild to exclude all folders where one is found by adding this to the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_CslaResourcesAssemblies Include="**/Csla.Resources.dll" />
  <Content Update="@(_CslaResourcesAssemblies->'%(RecursiveDir)**')" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```