# How to add a folder in deployment in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api, .net-core

I am trying to add an entire folder in the publication files, I have found several configurations but none of them work for me, for example

[ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish/42713770)

But it does not work for me, the folder I want to add is in the root of my project.

[image]

And I want to see it in the publication archives in this way

[image]

I have tried to add the folder to the publication in this way

[image]

I am using .NET CORE 2.1 and Visual Studio 15.7.5

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* it's hard to tell unless you tell us what your doing? The question you linked seems to cover everything you need. I'm not sure what you want this question to add?

Comment: [When we ask a question about a problem with our code, we have to let the people who are helping us see it. Images of our code do not qualify.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I have edited the question adding the implementation I am doing

Comment: also, what type of applications is this? Console app, Class library, web page? Etc.

Comment: is an API with MVC

Comment: and where do you expect this folder to be when you publish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files are located in or below the `wwwroot` folder, just set the `Build Action` to `Content` (for each file) and it will get copied when publishing.

(My project only uses files below wwwroot, so I can't comment on a different folder.)

There is no need to manually edit the csproj.

Comment: Very good observation, if I add it in wwwroot the folder is added in the publication, but my project is an API, then I do not want to leave the Queries folder there

Answer (score 0):

If the folder/files is above the wwwroot folder, then right-click on the file and select "properties".  In the properties window/pane, set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer". This will post the folders and files in the right directory during the "Publish" process.