# Unable to load static file once it has been published to Azure, using ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Using `ASP.NET Core 2.1`, I'm trying to load the same static file locally on my dev machine (through Visual Studio 2017) and after the website has been published to the hosting environment (Azure Web Apps).

Consider the directory hierarchy in which the static file (`file.xml`) to be served resides inside the web root:

```
wwwroot
    css
    images
    js
    xml
        file.xml
```

Here's my controller to load the file:

```
public class DevelopmentController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public DevelopmentController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public async Task<string> Test()
    {
        string result = "";

       // Test Code Here
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "xml", "file.xml"));

        return result;
    }
}
```

This loads the file locally on my dev machine, however, once the web app is published to Azure, I get the following error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\xml\file.xml'

No matter what I try, I cannot seem to load the file after it has been published to Azure.

NOTE: In `ASP.NET MVC 5`, I used to be able to use the `Server.MapPath()` function to load a static file, which worked both locally and in Azure. For example:

```
doc.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/xml/file.xml"));
```

But since upgrading to `ASP.NET Core 2.1`, I can't figure out the proper way to do this, that will also work when hosted on Azure.

These are the Microsoft Docs, I've used as reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

**UPDATE**

In case anyone else experiences the same issue, this is what the problem was:

If you drag and drop a folder into `Solution Explorer`, the reference does not get automatically added to the `.csproj` file.

You can check your `.csproj` file by right clicking on the project and selecting `Edit {Project Name}.csproj`. For any extra folders you've added to the `wwwroot` directory, you should see something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\myfolder\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you don't see that, then it won't be published to Azure.

NOTE: If you see `<None ...`, then that means that the folder has been set to be excluded from publishing.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\myexcludedfolder\"
</ItemGroup>
```

**SOLUTION**

I just deleted the folder that I had drag and dropped into Solution Explorer, and instead right clicked `wwwroot` to create the folder that way.

Comment: Please start with [this guidance](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues) to determine whether it's a deployment or runtime issue.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about Kudu. It does appear that the folder in wwwroot is not being published to Azure for some reason. Feel free to add your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as correct. And if you have any suggestion about fixing the folder not being published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your issue is that this file is not getting published, and it is not an issue with what happens at runtime.

You would probably see the same behavior if you ran `dotnet publish` locally, with that file probably missing from the publish folder.

As for *why* it is not getting published, I'm not an expert of that part, but this answer might help: [ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish)

Comment: Thanks again David. That article, although specific to ASP.NET Core 1.0, was helpful to get me on the right track. I'll update my question with the steps to fix the publish folders for ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this question but for `.js` files (or similar), make sure your `environment` is set correctly in your `View`.

Default example would be this:

```
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Where all work was done into `site.js` **NOT** `site.min.js`. Publishing will use a different `environment` than what you're developing in and that makes an impact on your results.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_env.ContentRootPath + "\\xml\\file.xml", FileMode.Open);
```