# Copy file (geckodriver.exe) to publish folder when publishing ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 project

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, asp.net-core, csproj, geckodriver

Using [firefox geckodriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver/0.22.0/) in ASP.NET Core, I noticed that `geckodriver.exe` is copied to `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`, which work fine during debugging. But after publishing, it's not present in `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish`.

So I'm trying to [copy it using csproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713770/3276634) with this `ItemGroup`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(TargetDir)\geckodriver.exe" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The file is found, cause when I change the path to `$(TargetDir)\geckodriver2.exe` I get an error that `geckodriver2.exe` doesn't exist. But it doesn't copy `geckodriver.exe` to `publish` directory.

Answer (score 1):

After manually deleting `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish` and running `dotnet publish` I noticed that `geckodriver` was copied to `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`. So it seems that my file was not copied for some kind of caching issue.

Since the destination is still wrong, I found [this blogpost about copying files](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx) which gave me the right hint:

```
<Content Include="$(TargetDir)\geckodriver.exe" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always">
    <Link>geckodriver.exe</Link>
</Content>
```

Now the executable is correctly copied to `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish`.