# Web deployment package: Skip files when deploying

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-4.0, webdeploy

I want to create a web deployment package which leaves certain existing directories alone when deploying, e.g. a "logs" folder. Currently the package deletes/overwrites all existing files.

I can exclude the folder by adding extra parameters when executing the `foo.deploy.cmd` in the package, eg.:

```
 .\foo.deploy.cmd /T """-skip:Directory=\\logs"""
```

This seem to work. But I can't figure out how to include this configuration in the package itself so it will be applied automatically.

I have a Asp.net Core website on .net framework 4.7. I use Visual studio 2019 with a pubxml publish profile.

I have tried adding `MsDeploySkipRules` to the pubxml but they don't seem to be passed to the package parameters. I am unsure if `MsDeploySkipRules` should work with "Web Deploy Package" or only with "Web Deploy"?

Edit: The problem may be related to I'm using **Asp.net core**. The `MsDeploySkipRules` seem to be applied in a regular asp.net (added in the generated deploy.cmd script) project but not if I insert the same in an asp.net core project file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the below code in your .csproj file to skip the folder at the time of publishing.

```
    <ItemGroup>

    <Content Remove="wwwroot\test\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

also ste the delte existing file to true:

[image]

[ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish)

Comment: This seem to work for classic ASP.Net projects but not for ASP.Net Core projects.