# Maintain some folders when deploying with azure devops to azure webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, devops

I'm trying to find out how can I preserve some folders using Azure DevOps. I already got to deploy but this website has some folders with uploaded content that I can't override.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish

Comment: Is my answer useful to you ? If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is .net core 3.1, you can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

You can exclude file by the following  element excludes all files from the `wwwroot\content` folder. You can use it to keep your files not being changed when depoly.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
    <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath>wwwroot\\content</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can also refer to other methods in the official documentation to operate on the files or folders in the project when you publish it.