# How to copy custom JSON file into docker container?

Tags: json, docker, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I added custom json file in my .net core web API project and retrieved data from that json file successfully when running it in debug mode. But, problem arise when I run it as a docker container.

Error says "Missing custom.json file in '/app/' folder".

Comment: How did you add? Do you use `volume` or `COPY`?

Comment: I used COPY . .

Comment: Build image again, it seems it does not exist. Run an `ls -lh /app` to see if you have `custom.json`

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your .csproj file like below to include your `custom.json` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json">
    <RelativePath>azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json</RelativePath>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```

**For more details, you can refer below post.**

[ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish)