# How to remove unused code in js (adminlte) and css files in a blazor project

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly, adminlte

I have a Blazor Web assembly (wasm and asp core web api) and I've used AdminLte for the admin panel and now I want to reduce the project size.

1- I have many plugins (JS and CSS files) that I don't use them

2- In some CSS files I have a lot of code that I don't them anymore. like some CSS code for a dark mode that I don't use them.

I have 2 questions:

1- How to remove unused files & used code ( 1 & 2 as described ).

2- When I make the output from my code, does Visual Studio remove anused files (CSS & js) from wwwroot or it's my responsibility to do it?

Comment: If you want to simplify the current project, I do not recommend you to delete the relevant code of AdminLTE. If you are not very familiar with some codes of AdminLTE, it is possible that after you delete it, it will cause some abnormal display or function.

Comment: [ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713770/7687666)

Comment: is there any way to delete unused CSS files or code? for example, in the admin.css there is a lot of code for a dark mode that I don't use anymore and also there are a lot of plugins as well. because it's too heavy.