# How come my static files are when running locally but not served up when using UseStaticFiles and when running under AKS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-aks

When I run locally my static files under wwwroot are served up without problem as follows:

> https://localhost:5001/content/blah...

[image]

However, under aks (Azure Kubernetes Service, I get 404 not found when doing this:

> https://{myDns}/{myAksService}/content/blah...

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // Serve files from wwwroot

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider =
        new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot/.well-known")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true // serve extensionless file
});
```

My understanding is that the first UseStaticFiles should result in serving up the files under wwwroot

The .well-known files which are called out in separate UseStaticFiles are served up **without** issue under aks

> https://{myDns}/{myAksService}/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will save somebody a lot of trouble in the future, it was a case-sensitivity issue.

So in turns out that UseStaticFiles works just fine.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // Serve files from wwwroot
```

This was my problem:

- https://{myDns}/{myAksService}/content/blah (doesn't work)

This works:

- https://{myDns}/{myAksService}/**C**ontent/blah (works just fine)

My source code:

[image]

For further context my asp.net core service is running under AKS linux, and linux static files are case sensitive, see here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:~:text=configuration%20files%2C%20etc.-,The%20URLs,-for%20content%20exposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:%7E:text=configuration%20files%2C%20etc.-,The%20URLs,-for%20content%20exposed)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the folder `.well-known` not been included under the `wwwroot`. You can verify it by checking the publish files.

**How to fix it?**

We can include the foler and files while deploying the project.

[ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713770/7687666)